# Showing the union of two Lebesgue measurable sets is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

The following proof shows that two Lebesgue measurable sets are measurable, it goes as follows: 
[image]

(If this image is failing to load, here is a link in the meantime: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD37l.jpg)

**I am struggling to see how line $3$ is obtained from line $2$.**

More specifically, how do we get the term $m^*((F\setminus E_1) \setminus E_2 )$ in line $3$? All the other terms in line $3$ correspond to a term in line $2 $ except this last one. What am I missing?

Comment: Your link appears to be broken, so we can't see what you're referring to.

Comment: What is it saying?

Comment: Nothing: there's a broken link icon that, when clicked, goes to an empty page

Comment: Here is a link in the meantime: http://imgur.com/a/S91BV

Comment: I'll try fix the one in the post, it appears there is a problem with SE atm

Comment: well  in the picture there is a ] missing in line 3, so the term might be incomplete.

Comment: What is the source (title, author) for this extract ?

Answer (score 2):

The last member of line 2 is wrong, it should be $m^\ast(F\setminus(E_1\cup E_2))$, instead of $m^\ast(F\setminus(E_1\cap E_2))$.
Then

$(F\setminus E_1)\setminus E_2=(F\setminus E_1)\cap E_2^c=F\cap (E_1^c\cap E_2^c)=F\cap(E_1\cup E_2)^c=F\setminus(E_1\cup E_2)$

It seems to be a typo in your text.

Answer (score 0):

$F-(E_{1}\cup E_{2})=F\cap E_{1}^{c}\cap E_{2}^{c}=(F-E_{1})-E_{2}$

The second line is wrong. $F-(E_{1}\cup E_{2})$ instead of $F-(E_{1}\cap E_{2})$ inside of $m^{*}$.